# Styling lost when placing a <div> inside a <a> tag

Tags: css, html

Currently, I have a box which has some text inside it. Currently, the link is only applied to some text as below:

```
<div class="row text-banner-blocks">
<div class="col-sm-4 header-text-banner text-center">
 <!-- gray-border -->
  <div class="box">
     <h3>Free delivery worldwide*</h3>
     <a href="#">
     *More info here
     </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it appears on the site:

https://snag.gy/sbC421.jpg

However, I want the whole link placed in the whole box and as with HTML I just place the  tag inside the  tag but I seem to lose all the styling and the padding goes I think? Code:

```
<div class="row text-banner-blocks">
<div class="col-sm-4 header-text-banner text-center">
<!-- gray-border -->
<a href="#">
  <div class="box">
     <h3>Free delivery worldwide*</h3>
     <br/>
     *More info here
  </div>
</a>
</div>
```

This is how it looks after:

https://snag.gy/KZzSUv.jpg

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us your CSS

Comment: Put `display: block` on the `a` tag?

Comment: And why are you adding an Anchor tag? do you want to have href, or you are fine by handling the click in jquery? because you can apply click event to div.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also check if your Style sheets contain specific styles for Anchor tag, you can overwrite them in your tag by adding inline style.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referencing the `.box` div using a css selector that requires the parent element to be a div
so you might have to change the css for the box element to something like

```
a > .box {
   /* styles */
}
```

[check this image for more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JldW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Decided to do it with JavaScript inside using the below for the parameters of the div tag:

```
onclick="document.location='#'"
```

This solution is neater for what I am after and as I am using several style sheets it was difficult to spot the culprit.